# Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая после "когда проходил мимо"?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Давран не мог бы сосчитать, сколько, да он даже когда проходил мимо старался не смотреть в ту сторону, хотя за время осады привык к виду и запаху смерти.

Answer (score 1):

**Давран не мог бы сосчитать сколько, да он, даже когда проходил мимо, старался не смотреть в ту сторону, хотя за время осады привык к виду и запаху смерти.**

Оборот "даже когда проходил мимо" требуется выделить запятыми.

**Лопатин**:

> Если перед простым подчинительным союзом стоят
> усилительно-ограничительные слова (частицы, союзы или их сочетания,
> вводные слова) *особенно, даже, в частности, в том числе, в
> особенности, а именно, а также, а (но) только, как раз, лишь,
> исключительно, только* и др., то запятая ставится перед ними, а не
> перед союзом...

**Замечу также**, что запятой перед "сколько" быть не должно:

> <Запятая не ставится>, если придаточная часть состоит из одного
> союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): Я бы тоже
> желал знать  почему (Л.Т.); Не знаю  почему,  но я его не понимал
> (Триф.); Он ушёл и не сказал  куда;  Он обещал скоро вернуться, но не
> уточнил  когда;  Трудно сказать  почему;  Мать определяла температуру
> ребёнка губами: приложит их ко лбу и сразу определит  сколько;  Кто-то
> подал больному чашку воды, он даже не взглянул кто; Я не скажу  какое,
> я говорю — большое несчастье **(Розенталь, Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация, § 33.4)**.

Comment: @ Nektoid Уважаемый участник и мой друг (как я еще надеюсь)! Я обращаюсь к вам с повторной просьбой:  пишите в начале ответа то предложение, которое  вы считаете ВЕРНЫМ (то есть не отдельные фрагменты,  а в полном объеме),  В нескольких ваших ответах я действительно не могу этого понять, например здесь. Что там  решили писать: запятую, тире и ли тире с запятой. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/469975/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-тире-и-словом-словно-в-придаточном-определительном-пред

Comment: Спасибо за понимание.  Конечно, не все так делают, но ваши ответов это касается в первую очередь. Вам это не трудно, а читать вас будет  проще намного.

Comment: @Sharon хорошо; я просто не понял вначале, что речь идёт именно о полном предложении в его верном, на мой взгляд, варианте :)

Comment: @Sharon кстати, в ответе по ссылке я же пришёл к выводу, что допустимы оба варианта (и такая ситуация нередка). Как в таких случаях писать?

Comment: Вот видите, а я вообще ничего не поняла, что вы выбрали в конечно счете.  Как делаю я? Если я сразу вижу два варианта, то записываю их оба. Если это выясняется позже, то пишу отдельно, но стараюсь как-то выделить (подчеркнуть) второй вариант. Я на форуме собираю для себя интересные вопросы, и поэтому мне хочется четко понимать данные участниками ответы, Но это уже личная заинтересованность :)  Поэтому пжста, если вам не трудно.

Comment: Спасибо! Вот теперь прекрасный ответ, и про "сколько" тоже написали.

Answer (score 0):

Слова ‟проходил” и ‟старался” — однородные сказуемые, между которыми ставится запятая. Правильная пунктуация следующая: ‟Давран не мог бы сосчитать [здесь нет запятой, так как придаточное из одного союзного слова] сколько, да он даже когда проходил мимо, старался не смотреть в ту сторону, хотя за время осады привык к виду и запаху смерти.”