# Нужна ли запятая перед тире и словом "словно" в придаточном определительном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение придумано с ходу, прошу не придираться к кривому стилю. Написано лишь для примера конструкции.

*Он выкидывал с балкона вещи, которые с шумом разбивались о мостовую(,) - словно тысяча пользователей СтакЭксчейндж бросали банки с огурцами в стены дома.*

Comment: Что за сравнение такое?!.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я же специально попросил не придираться)) Сравнение нужно было лишь для конструкции.

Comment: К стилю не придираться просили, а тут не стиль, а смысл странный. ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от того, относите ли вы *словно тысяча пользователей СтакЭксчэнж бросали банки с огурцами в стены дома* только к той части предложения, что после запятой, или ко всему предложению.

Сравните:

> Это не вода плещет, меня не обманешь, — это его длинные вёсла.

Или:

> Это не вода плещет, меня не обманешь — даже не пытайтесь.

Во втором случае конструкция, присоединённая тире, относится только к части предложения *"меня не обманешь"*.

Comment: Получается, здесь нет единого правила и все зависит от мнения автора?

Comment: какой вариант лучше использовать для сравнительных конструкций, начинающихся со слова "словно"? Лучше ставить эту запятую, как я понял?

Comment: @Theej Не совсем от мнения. Попробуйте изъять часть предложения в первом и втором варианте. В первом это сделать легко: *Это не вода плещет — это его длинные вёсла*. Во втором — невозможно без потери смысла: *Это не вода плещет — даже не пытайтесь*. Вам тоже надо понять, к чему присобачен сравнительный оборот. *Он выкидывал с балкона вещи, словно тысяча пользователей...* или же *вещи, выкинутые с балкона, разбивались с таким шумом, словно....*

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Стало понятнее.

Comment: @Theej запятая перед словно (будто, точно, нежели и т. п.) может ставиться или не ставиться в зависимости от того, играет ли оборот роль сравнения или отождествления. Подробнее: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125 § 88 и § 90.

Comment: да, это я помню. Меня смутил конкретно мой пример, где используется тире.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже отмечали участники форума, смысл и стиль здесь выглядят странно. И вот в этом случае   работать с таким предложением довольно сложно.

1. Запись этого предложения могла бы выглядеть так:

***(1) Он выкидывал с балкона вещи, (2) которые с ТАКИМ шумом разбивались о мостовую, (3) СЛОВНО тысяча пользователей СтакЭксчейндж бросали банки с огурцами в стены дома.***

Это СПП с последовательным подчинением двух определительных придаточных. Предложение (3) является определительным по отношению к (2), связь местоименно-союзная (такой...словно). Сравнить: У неё было такое выражение лица, будто она знала что-то.

2. А это предложенный вариант.

***Он выкидывал с балкона вещи, которые с шумом разбивались о мостовую,  – словно тысяча пользователей СтакЭксчейндж бросали банки с огурцами в стены дома.***

Семантика не очень ясна, но лучше поставить **запятую и тире**.  Предложение нужно разделить на блоки, поэтому используется единый знак. Два блока соответствуют двум ситуациям, которые сопоставляются между собой (будем считать, что с точки зрения семантики это именно так).

Сопоставление (уподобление) ситуаций соответствует определению **придаточных сравнительных предложений** в грамматике, поэтому я использую этот термин.  Здесь сравниваются ситуации, описанные в предложениях (1), (2) и в предложении (3).

Comment: Для справки: перелом конструкции — это когда структурно не стыкуется, например: *Пусть я даже ошибаюсь, — что ж, ошибаться свойственно человеку.* Нормальная структура: *Пусть я даже ошибаюсь, но своего решения не изменю.* А в примере из вопроса от наличия запятой зависит, к какому простому предложению относится оборот (то есть что сравнивается), у вас — к главному (*выкидывал вещи, словно тысяча человек*).

Comment: Вы в начале предлагаете без тире, чтобы отнести к придаточному. Тогда получается: *которые разбивались, словно пользователи бросали*. Что-то здесь не то. Глаголы не соотносятся. А здесь соотносятся: *он выкидывал, словно пользователи бросали*.

Comment: А то, что глаголы разные, стоит обсудить. Прихожу к выводу, что глаголы должны соотноситься, если они вообще могут быть разными.

Answer (score 2):

КОММЕНТАРИЙ К ОТВЕТУ

Цитата:

«Для справки: **перелом конструкции** — это когда структурно не стыкуется, например: Пусть я даже ошибаюсь, — что ж, ошибаться свойственно человеку. Нормальная структура: Пусть я даже ошибаюсь, но своего решения не изменю.

А в примере из вопроса **от наличия запятой зависит, к какому простому предложению относится оборот** (то есть что сравнивается), у вас — к главному (выкидывал вещи, словно тысяча человек)». **– oleedd**

**Перелом конструкции** – термин не точный, а скорее описательный,  у Розенталя он вообще дается в кавычках. Поэтому не стоит приписывать  этому понятию только свое собственное толкование.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=152#pp152  пункт 3
3. Запятая и тире ставятся для обозначения «перелома» первоначальной конструкции, для указания, «с одной стороны, на расчлененность предложения, а с другой — на то, что та его часть, которая следует за этим знаком препинания, делает структурный поворот от предшествующей части под некоторым, большим или меньшим, “углом”»

**И вывод**

Дорогие друзья, пожалуйста, относитесь к грамматике серьезней, чем вы это делаете сейчас. Это мое доброе к вам пожелание.

P.S. А все остальное я стерла, потому что не нравится (извините).  В этом предложении семантика плохо сочетается с предложенной грамматикой — и так плохо, и так нехорошо.

В принципе здесь должны сравниваться **две ситуации**, например: Он приехал сразу же, как я позвонил, — будто ждал моего звонка. Здесь все понятно, никаких проблем.

А с огурцами как-то все сложно: не то он вещи бросал, как бросают банки; не то они разбивались, как разбиваются банки. В общем, вывод такой: для некорректного (или неясного) предложения не может быть правильного решения, лучше и не пробовать.

Comment: Серьёзность отношения к грамматике измеряется количеством страниц из АГ-80, вываленных на автора вопроса, просто соорудившего не слишком уклюжий пример. Всосал на будущее, начальнегг.

Comment: Представьте себя врачом. К вам приходят больные со своими проблемами, и первым делом вы должны определиться с диагнозом, а потом уже назначать лечение. Для этого нужны и все ваши знания, и практический опыт. Так и с предложением.  С ним что-то не так (это определяется на слух) , но что именно? (Перечитайте диалог в начале вопроса.)  С чего вы начнете, с  лечения наугад? Попробуем то, попробуем это. Нет, желательно определить диагноз, а это всегда грамматика. И автору вопроса  всё  «вываливать»  ни к чему, ему обычно нужна краткая информация простыми словами: что неправильно и как исправить.

Comment: По моему мнению, хорошо, когда отвечающий на форумах обладает не только знаниями, но ещё и, так сказать, чутьём психолога. Нередко бывает, что автор вопроса просто не сумел соорудить корректный пример, а лишённые эмпатии филологи уже родили обсуждение на 20 страниц :) Вы вот спрашивали, мол, как насчёт того, чтобы определить вид придаточных, — а учли ли, что автор в заголовке вопроса указал: он имеет в виду придаточное определительное?

Comment: *делает структурный поворот от предшествующей части под некоторым, большим или меньшим, “углом"* — вот это указывает на перелом структуры, ведь конструкция и есть структура. Использовать этот термин где попало уж точно не вариант. У Розенталя в разных темах тире добавляется к запятой, когда надо соотнести с первым фрагментом, а не с предыдущим (вторым). Тире с запятой нельзя ставить только из-за увеличенной паузы. Что с предложением не так? Что не понравилось Артёму? Вероятно, то, что оно про всех нас, ведь СтакЭксчейндж — это этот сайт. Мы ведь не любим бросать банки с огурцами.

Comment: *А с огурцами как-то все сложно: не то он вещи бросал, как бросают банки; не то они разбивались, как разбиваются банки* — вот, а там глаголы разные. Нельзя разбиваться так, как что-то бросают. То есть там не подчинение. Тогда там самостоятельное предложение: *Он выкидывал с балкона вещи, которые с шумом разбивались о мостовую, [это было так,] словно тысяча пользователей СтакЭксчейндж бросали банки с огурцами в стены дома.*